# Como escolher as colunas específicas de uma tabela em python

Tags: python, pandas, matriz

Bom pessoal, estou com uma tabela e estou querendo retornar em uma variavel x apenas algumas colunas dessa tabela e para isto estou utilizando o .iloc

Exemplo: `x_dataset = dataset.iloc[:, 29 & 19].values` (sendo os valores 29 e 19 as colunas que eu quero na minha variavel x_dataset
O retorno teria que ser este:

```
array([[  4., 238.],
       [  4., 238.],
       [  3., 238.],
       ...,
       [  2., 185.],
       [  3., 185.],
       [  3., 185.]])
```

Sendo os primeiros valores da coluna 29 e os segundos valores da coluna 19 (Não necessariamente preciso que seja nessas posições 0 e 1)

Pesquisei outros exemplos e a documentação e não achei nada parecido, acho que não sei como pesquisar isso também kkkkkk. Fico grato pela ajuda!

Comment: Seria interessante você mostrar uma amostra dos seus dados

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Você tem que passar uma lista das colunas que você quer.
Por exemplo, você tem seguinte dataframe:

| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 6 | 11 | 16 | 21 |
| 2 | 7 | 12 | 17 | 22 |
| 3 | 8 | 13 | 18 | 23 |

E quer retornar as colunas col4 e col5, você deve fazer:

```
import pandas as pd

df = df.iloc[:,[3,4]]
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, era exatamente isso que estava precisando!